# flutter material pickers issue update

Tags: java, flutter

When I am trying to do flutter pub, I get this error:

```
[owner] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in owner...                           
Because flutter_material_pickers <1.9.0 depends on intl ^0.16.0 and every version of flutter_localizations from sdk depends on intl 0.17.0, flutter_material_pickers <1.9.0 is incompatible with flutter_localizations from sdk.

So, because the owner depends on both flutter_localizations any from sdk and flutter_material_pickers 1.7.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because owner depends on both flutter_localizations any from sdk and flutter_material_pickers 1.7.1, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

this is my
*pubspec.yml* :

```
name: owner
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  location: 3.0.1
  google_maps_flutter: 0.5.31
  geocoder: ^0.2.1
  transformer_page_view: 0.1.6
  auto_size_text: 2.1.0
  shared_preferences: 0.5.4+5
  notifier: 1.0.2
  fluttertoast: 4.0.1
  rxdart: 0.24.1
  http: ^0.12.0+1
  firebase_messaging: ^5.0.4
  image_picker: 0.6.7+4
  flutter_material_pickers: 1.7.1
  flutter_local_notifications: 1.4.4+4
  image:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter 

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - Assets/OnBoarding1.png
    - Assets/OnBoarding2.png
    - Assets/OnBoarding3.png
    - Assets/AppLogo/owner.jpg
    - Assets/Dashboard/restaurant.jpg
    - Assets/Dashboard/resBanner.jpg
    - Assets/Food/Italiyan_Pasta.jpg
    - Assets/Food/pizza.jpg
    - Assets/Food/veg.png
    - Assets/Food/nonVeg.png
    - Assets/Profile/myProfile.png
    - Assets/changePassword/passwordSuccess.png
    - Assets/flags/brazil.png
    - Assets/flags/canada.png
    - Assets/flags/spain.png
    - Assets/flags/uae.png
    - Assets/flags/usa.png
    - Assets/Notification/bell.png
    - Assets/Success/mail.png
    - Assets/AddRestaurant/placeholder.jpg

    

    
  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Quicksand
      fonts:
        - asset: Assets/Font/Quicksand-Bold.ttf
        - asset: Assets/Font/Quicksand-Light.ttf
        - asset: Assets/Font/Quicksand-Medium.ttf
        - asset: Assets/Font/Quicksand-Regular.ttf
          weight: 700
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

I have tried to solve this issue by downloading the flutter_material_pickers and it didn't give me any kind of solution still. Please try to help me. I have posted the code above and hope you can give me an idea to solve the issue. I have tried to add dependency intl : ^0.16.0 but it still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Change version of `flutter_material_pickers` to higher than 1.9.0

```
flutter_material_pickers: 1.9.2
```